# asp.net Button OnClick event doesn't work while using page transitions

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

So basically my issue is that the button OnClick event doesn't fire up while using smoothstate.js for page transitions. if the page (Default.aspx) is loaded and I move to another page (Second.aspx) where the button is located, OnClick event won't work (it simply redirects to the previous postback page) unless I refresh the page (Second.aspx).

Master Page:

```
<form runat="server">
...
<div id="main" class="m-scene">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

Second.aspx

```
<div class="container scene-element scene-element--fade-in-left">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       ...
       <asp:Button ID="test" OnClick="ButtonClick1" runat="server" Text="test" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Hope I'm clear with my issue. Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: If it works correctly when you refresh, then the issue is you have not done what `smoothstate.js` recommends. I don't know `smoothstate.js` so I can't help.

Comment: well, page transitions work perfectly fine. I just don't seem to get a full control over the page, unless I refresh it.

Comment: I know. That has to be related to smoothstate

Comment: Got the same problem on a different project once more, however using a different js for page transitions (swup,js). Basically it seems like whenever I'm applying page transitions to a certain pages that have the asp button on them, it will redirect back to the default page whenever the button is pressed. The only way to prevent this issue I've found so far is to disable smooth page transition for the pages that use any kind of Button action... Anyone else got ideas?